# How to stop particular "proxy" like site from copying websites?

Tags: proxy

A few days ago we noticed a site on google that is an exact copy of several sites and we would like to stop it but we don't know how to, the ip is hidden by cloudflare and the domain registration is private, and even with that info we don't think they will cooperate, they seem to be some kind of Russian scammer, so far it copied about 10 websites.

example:
real site: https://gbatemp.net
copy site: http://gbatemp.gukovo.org/

The problem is they are already ranking well in google and people is accessing them and giving credentials.

Any info or ideas appreciated.

Comment: If you are the owner of the copied website (and copyright holder) then you could send a [takedown](http://www.dmca.com/FAQ/What-is-a-DMCA-Takedown) request to cloudflare. Here is a [sample takedown letter](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2009/07/06/sample-dmca-take-down-letter/id=4501/).

Comment: @DavidPostill Very good answer!!!

Comment: We are waiting for an answer from cloudflare. But even if they stop using cloudflare that will not stop them.

Comment: I believe that you can also ask the search engines to stop listing them.  I'm not sure how well that would work.  It might be the same sort of moving-target problem you get with spammers; you shut them down at one address, and they pop back up at another.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I to stop particular "proxy" like site from copying websites?

If you are the owner of the copied website (and copyright holder) then you could send a [DMCA Takedown](http://www.dmca.com/FAQ/What-is-a-DMCA-Takedown) request to cloudflare.

Note:

> Although the DMCA is part of US Copyright law, a DMCA Takedown does not require the content to be copyrighted in order to process the takedown OR for the request to have the content taken down acted upon by the website owner or ISP.

Source [What is a DMCA Takedown?](http://www.dmca.com/FAQ/What-is-a-DMCA-Takedown)

---

#### Sample Takedown Letter

> My name is INSERT NAME and I am the INSERT TITLE of INSERT COMPANY
>   NAME.  A website that your company hosts (according to WHOIS
>   information) is infringing on at least one copyright owned by my
>   company.
>
> An article was copied onto your servers without permission. The
>   original ARTICLE/PHOTO, to which we own the exclusive copyrights, can
>   be found at:
>
> PROVIDE WEBSITE URL
>
> The unauthorized and infringing copy can be found at:
>
> PROVIDE WEBSITE URL
>
> This letter is official notification under Section 512(c) of the
>   Digital Millennium Copyright Act (”DMCA”), and I seek the removal of
>   the aforementioned infringing material from your servers. I request
>   that you immediately notify the infringer of this notice and inform
>   them of their duty to remove the infringing material immediately, and
>   notify them to cease any further posting of infringing material to
>   your server in the future.
>
> Please also be advised that law requires you, as a service provider,
>   to remove or disable access to the infringing materials upon receiving
>   this notice. Under US law a service provider, such as yourself, enjoys
>   immunity from a copyright lawsuit provided that you act with
>   deliberate speed to investigate and rectify ongoing copyright
>   infringement. If service providers do not investigate and remove or
>   disable the infringing material this immunity is lost. Therefore, in
>   order for you to remain immune from a copyright infringement action
>   you will need to investigate and ultimately remove or otherwise
>   disable the infringing material from your servers with all due speed
>   should the direct infringer, your client, not comply immediately.
>
> I am providing this notice in good faith and with the reasonable
>   belief that rights my company owns are being infringed. Under penalty
>   of perjury I certify that the information contained in the
>   notification is both true and accurate, and I have the authority to
>   act on behalf of the owner of the copyright(s) involved.
>
> Should you wish to discuss this with me please contact me directly.
>
> Thank you.
>
> /s/YOUR NAME
>
> Address City, State Zip Phone E-mail

Source [Sample DMCA Take Down Letter](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2009/07/06/sample-dmca-take-down-letter/id=4501/)